# Embedding Windows media player in C# any other alternative?

Tags: c#, .net, media-player, audio-streaming

I am using embedded version of Windows media player 11+ using C# in a windows application. Is there any better alternative to play audio? I am looking to play audio and will not be playing videos at all.

Windows media player plays well but I am curious about other alternatives as well.

Answer (score 0):

[FMOD](http://fmod.org) is a very nice free library that, while game-oriented, supports many formats and has a full-featured C# API.

It's extremely easy to use (for simple scenarios) and comes with lots of examples.